# Mobile menu accordion logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an accordion for a mobile menu and I'm trying to prevent having multiply sections(subnavs) open.

Here is my working js that will open and close subnav but each section in an independent manner.(where more than one subnav can be open):

Markup:

```
<ul class="navigation-menu">
   <li class="white-hover">
      <div class="drop">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
  jQuery('.white-hover').click(function(e) {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('drop-down');
      jQuery(this).find(".drop").toggleClass('mobil-active');
 });
```

Here is my attempt to collapse open sections if any using .each:

Js:

```
  jQuery('.white-hover').click(function(e) {

     jQuery('.white-hover').find(".drop").each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('mobil-active'));
        {
           jQuery(this).toggleClass('mobil-active');
        }
     });

     jQuery(this).toggleClass('drop-down');
     jQuery(this).find(".drop").toggleClass('mobil-active');
  });
```

All I want to achieve is to only have one section open at a time. If the user was to click on a closed section it should open it and close the rest if they are to be open.

Comment: I would do it by removing the drop-down class from all elements then add to the clicked element and not play with ifs and toggles.

Comment: I would use a plugin, I have used Design Chemical's Accordion Navigation for a long time. It's stable, works with jQuery versions going back and current (2.x). Puts classes on the parent, active, and so forth. Here's an example: https://jsbin.com/wavapu/1/ (https://jsbin.com/wavapu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking to do? You can use `.siblings()` to find the other menus and close them instead of using an `if` statement:

```
$('.white-hover').click(function() {
  $(this).find(".drop ul").slideDown().end().siblings("li").find(".drop ul").slideUp();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmvdtba6/)